# How to allow users to insert angular scope variables into a text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textarea like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="content"></textarea>
{{content}}
```

And a variable like this:

```
$scope.name = 'Billy'
```

I want to allow the user to be able to insert variables into the textarea, so that if they put:

```
Hello {{name}}
```

The output of `{{content}}` could be `Hello Billy`

I may also want to simplify it so that the user could type in something like: `Hello [Name]` into the textarea and it parses in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/0VH106Gxz7xjhCj5NMpT?p=preview

It would probably be best to put this in a directive. But here is fast and dirty

```
app = angular.module('plunkr', []);

app.controller('messages', function($scope, $interpolate){
  $scope.name = 'billy';
  $scope.evalText = function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
    $scope.message = $interpolate(msg)($scope)
  }

});
```

Comment: Works amazing! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I got the question right, try using [interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate).

Answer (score 1):

[codenamejames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1456666/codenamejames)
is to the point. But if anyone wants to use it globally they can extend it to create a filter as following.

```
<html ng-app="nameApp">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
      <textarea ng-init="content='Name is {{name}}'" ng-model="content"></textarea>
       {{content | compile:this}}
  </body>
</html>
```

With following Js:

```
var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', []);
nameApp.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.name = 'John';
  });

nameApp.filter('compile', function($interpolate) {
  return function(input, scope) {
    return input ? $interpolate(input)(scope) : '';
  };
})
```

Live Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaZpaO